# getting an object from a List of inherited classes in c#

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I have a list of objects which are of the base type T but they are all different subclasses say T1, T2 etc. which inherit from T. There is one object of each type in this list.

How do I get an element from the list which is of type T1?

Comment: Look up the `is` keyword (Despite/In addition to the Linq answers, look up for loops as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like:

```
var itemsOfT1 = yourList.OfType<T1>();
```

If you need a single item then use:

```
var itemOfT1 = yourList.OfType<T1>().FirstOrDefault();
```

See: [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with List.OfType(). As shown here: [Enumerable.OfType Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
 T1 t1=null;
 foreach(var item in list)
  {
   if(item is T1)
   {
     t1 =item as T1;
     break;
   }
  }
```